# Git clone command fails when running inside a GitHub workflow

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow

I have a Linux sever and git clone and git pull commands (I have registered SSH keys with GitHub) are working fine when I use them in OS. Then, I wanted to setup a pipeline in GitHub. So, I added following code(.yml) into the workflow folder of my repo.

```
name: Build and Deploy FE App
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Deploy to Linux Server
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
      with:
        host: ${{ secrets.SERVER_HOST }}
        username: ${{ secrets.SERVER_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.SERVER_PASSWORD }}
        script: |
          cd ../../www/wwwroot/
          rm -rf frontend/
          git clone git@github.my_org/my_frontend.git
          npm install
          npm run build
          rm -rf ../myorg/assets
          rm -rf ../myorg/images
          rm -rf ../myorg/myleo
          mv -vf dist/* ../myorg
```

When running the pipeline, I am getting the following error,

```
err: Host key verification failed.
err: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
err: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
err: and the repository exists.
err: npm WARN config init.module Use `--init-module` instead.
```

Can someone please help me to clarify why SSH keys in the server are not identified by GitHub inside a pipeline.

Comment: Does `git clone` command work by directly SSHing into your remote server from your local machine? Seems like that needs to be fixed. Not directly related to GitHub Actions though. Check this https://askubuntu.com/questions/45679/ssh-connection-problem-with-host-key-verification-failed-error.